# DocuSign AnchorString

Tags: json, docusignapi, anchor

So I am brand new into the customizing of DocuSign and am wondering if I can get some help with what I'm trying to do

[image]

I am able to locate and find a anchorstring, but I am wondering how to I utilize offsetting above or below located anchorstring based on Staff I, Staff II, Staff III, and Director?

Answer (score -1):

Certainly, you can calculate the offset from the AnchorTabString's position to the desired location for placing the tab. The point of reference for this calculation is the bottom-left corner of the AnchorTabString, which is considered as the origin (0,0). The tab graphic is then positioned relative to this origin. If you have positive XOffset values, it means you're shifting the tab to the right on the page, and positive YOffset values mean you're moving the tab down on the page. [Using Anchor Tags](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/esign101/anchor-tagging/using-anchor-tags/)

For example, In your document it contains the text Sign1. If you want to place a signature tab by each instance where this string is found in the document then, place a tab one inch to the right of the string to make sure the Sign1 does not overwrite it, you could use the following tab definition:

```
"tabs": { "Details": [{ "anchorString": "sIGN1", "anchorXOffset": "1", "anchorYOffset": "0", "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false", "anchorUnits": "inches" }] }
```

[Auto-place (anchor tagging)](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/)

Comment: Sign1, I was under the impression that the anchorstring is whatever I dictate. So I thought Staff I, Staff II, Staff III, and Director are my unique anchorstrings. Where would my document contain Sign1?

Comment: Sorry, If your document contains staff1, staff II ,staff III & Director then if you want to place anchor strings near these values it should be as below. 
"tabs": { "Details": [{ "anchorString": "Staff I", "anchorXOffset": "1", "anchorYOffset": "0", "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false", "anchorUnits": "inches" }] }